# Protecting intellectual property (resources like images, sounds, ...and other media) in an android application from copy

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an android application which basically shows images and play sounds. All these files are embedded in the application, so will be downloaded with the app from play market on the users devices.
For the code i'll use Proguard Code Obfuscation, but how about media?

Is there a way to protect somehow all the media, and prevent the guys who loves to clone apps from get all the pictures and sounds?

Any ideas? maybe there is a magical solution, and i dont know it!
Thanks to All in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can ship encrypted media files with your app and Decrypt them on app launch,
Of-course, there will be extra burden of decryption on run-time, but your files will be secured.

Comment: That sound good, but what is the best way to encode the assets? 
I know that ProGuard only obfuscates the code, leaving the resources free to copy from apk.

Comment: That depends on your requirement or use-case.... May be all files in one encrypted zip archive or individual encrypted files.

Comment: For me it's not important which option to choose. The only condition is to protect them. I guess encrypting will be the easiest solution. But how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot protect it digitally. If your application can display it, it can be stolen. You can make it harder with techniques like encryption and obfuscation. But these have performance penalties and they don't make it impossible to steal.

The only way you can protect it is with good old lawsuit.

Comment: Yes agree, but in order to start a lawsuit, i will have to permanently scan the web for apps that are using my intellectual property. Very time consuming, and i guess it wont worth.

Comment: Most of the time it is probably not worth your time no. Unless you are actually loosing a massive amount of money because of it.